# Regular expression to match optional numeric string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression to match a string somthing like

Sample:

```
3232asdfADFF/ew323fdffADF 4243dsafAFDF 232 (total 42)
<----p1---->/<---p2-----> <----p3----> P4
```

I could successfully match till `p3` but unable to match last part i.e. `p4`
The `p4` is essentially numeric string, having length 0 to 3 (abscent or max 3).

I'm using:

```
[0-9A-Za-z]{2,12}/[0-9A-Za-z]{3,12} [0-9A-Za-z]{0,12}\\b \\d{0,3}$
```

But the problem I'm facing is that it fails if I completely remove `p4` from input.
And succeeds with even if on number.

Comment: When you remove the final numeric field do you still have a space character?

Comment: As for every question regarding regular expressions: What regular expression engine are you using? grep, egrep, perl, etc.

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're matching, or what could/could not be available for matching. You're using `[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,12}` (which tells me it's optional) but requiring a hard word break (`\b`) directly after. Shouldn't that also be optional?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, I think:

```
[0-9A-Za-z]{2,12}/[0-9A-Za-z]{3,12}(?: [0-9A-Za-z]{1,12})?(?: \\d{1,3})?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it fails if you have no space. You should have something like `( \d{0,3})?$` I think.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, not sure what may/may not exist in the pattern. But, best guess effort, here's what I've come up with:

```
\w{3,12}\/\w{3,12} (?:\w{0,12} )?\d{0,3}
```

That will match everything up until the `(total 42)`. If you need to include that as well, you can add:

```
(?: \(\w+ \d+\))?
```

To the end of the pattern. Again, *best effort* based on what I see and what I'm guessing should be the result. If it's not what you're going for, leave me a comment and I can adjust it.

*(Also, for the sake of length I replaced the `[0-9a-zA-Z]` with `\w`. Though it's not a direct one-to-one replacement, it was close. If you need it to be explicitly the previous pattern, replace the `\w` back to your original class.)*